# Alternative for SharedVariable

Tags: parallelization

I have the following code:

```
Answer = Table[Undefined, {1048576}];
SetSharedVariable[Answer];

ParallelDo[(

  eq = getEx[i];
  (* Some calculation here with eq *)
  Answer[[i]] = Solve[eq][[1]];

), {i, 1048576}];

Export["my_list.csv", Answer]
```

What `getEx[i]` does is to return me with an expression that I need to solve.

I need to get all 1M differents equations and save it´s answers, they are all independet of each other, so I could use parallel programming to speed thing a lot.

My problem is that with a SharedVariable, each kernel always goes to the main one for evaluation, so this code is almost slower then using a simple `Do[]` instead of `ParallelDo[]`

I would like to know how could I make this run better? Since I am just writing into a SharedVariable but never reading from that during the parallel programing.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look on that. I just started 2 days ago working with mathemathica.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use `ParallelTable` and dispense with the shared variable altogether? Also, make sure that the definition of `getEx` gets distributed: if it lives in `Global` that shouldn't be a problem, but if it lives in a package it might.

```
LaunchKernels[];
DistributeDefinitions[getEx];
solutions = ParallelTable[
  Solve[getEx[i]][[1]]
  {i, 1048576}
];
CloseKernels[];
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will try that

Comment: It worked perfectly!, Thanks!
My simulation was taking something around 3h, now I got that in 10 minuts

Comment: You're welcome. For future reference: in Mathematica you generally don't want to use `Do` loops to assemble lists. That's what `Table` and functions like `Map` (and their `Parallel` brothers) are for.